# UnityFramework Target is Missing

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, xcframework

I'm trying to build iOS project from existing Unity project. When I select "Build & Run", Unity creates .xworkspace which contain 2 projects, Unity-iPhone.xcodeproject & Pods.xcodeproject. Here when I check in Products folder, new product is getting created **"Unity-iPhone-New.app"** rather than UnityFramework.framework. Also, **UnityFramework target is missing.**

I'm very much newbie to Unity & wanted to create xcframework. I was able to do it with my simple poc project but with this existing project, I'm not able to create xcframework due to above issue. This project has few dependencies. It uses ARKit & VR from Unity. I'm currently using Unity version 2018.4.x

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the online documentations of [2019.2](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/Manual/StructureOfXcodeProject.html) and [2019.3](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/StructureOfXcodeProject.html), we can conclude that *UnityFramework.framework* was added in Unity 2019.3.